# Get String from sqlite table into array

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i try to get data from my table in sqlite

DatabaseHelper.java

```
...
public Cursor getAllData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    return res;
}
...
```

MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Cursor ress = myDb.getPartData();
    String[] id_pull = new String[ress.getCount()];

    if (ress.getCount() == 0) {
        int i = 0;
        while (ress.moveToNext()) {
            String uname = ress.getString(ress.getColumnIndex("ID"));
            id_pull[i] = uname;
            i++;
        }
    }else
    {Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}


...
```

there is 4 record on my sqlite table, i try to get string data and push to array (id_pull) but when i run this app, the app force close.
anyone can help fix my code :)

thanks

**Log Verbose**

> 11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.app.example.sqliteapp, PID: 22191
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.example.sqliteapp/com.app.example.sqliteapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.app.example.sqliteapp.DatabaseHelper.getPartData()' on a null object reference
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.app.example.sqliteapp.DatabaseHelper.getPartData()' on a null object reference
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.app.example.sqliteapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
>   11-12 15:51:43.981 22191-22191/com.app.example.sqliteapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)

Answer (score 1):

Create your DatabaseHelper before using it as such:

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper();
```

Comment: yes... problem solved. Thanks